# Setting Visibility="Collapsed" doesn't hide the Button. Update: Fixed by myself but I want to know the reason for the issue

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am creating a custom transport controls. In that, I have added an AppBarButton. To change the visibility of that I have created a Property for it, but for some reason, it doesn't work. The AppBarButton is always visible.

Code of the Property

```
//To change Visibility for CompactOverlayButton
public bool IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible
{
    get
    {
        return compactOverlayButton != null && compactOverlayButton.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
    }
    set
    {
        if (compactOverlayButton != null)       //To neglect the Visibility check before the Template has been applied
        {
            compactOverlayButton.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

So I started debugging it. I can't find any error in the C# part, so I set `Visibility="Collapsed"` for `AppBarButton` in the XAML part. I am surprised, Even though I set `Visibility="Collapsed"` the `AppBarButton` is still visible.

Here is my code in XAML part

```
<AppBarButton x:Name='CompactOverlayButton'
    Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
    MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='17' Visibility="Collapsed">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEE40;"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

**Update:**

I found out the line of code which is causing it. It is from the C# part of the page where I have used this `CustomMediaTransportControls`.

The Line which causing this is

```
var youtubeUrl = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("QTYVJhy04rs", YouTubeQuality.Quality144P, videoQuality);
```

I have fixed the issue problem by setting `CustomMediaControl.IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible = false;` after the above line of code. Still, I want to how the above line is affecting my program. The entire code the been included in the for reference part

**For Reference:**

Here is my entire code

1. [CustomMediaTransportControls.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve7s15zlxtn9aky/CustomMediaTransportControls.cs?dl=0) - Derived class from `MediaTransportControls`
2. [MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eg2s5p4cynao3dk/MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml?dl=0) - `ResourceDictionary`
3. [VideosPage.xaml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbyck5gyvpeg520/VideosPage.xaml.cs?dl=0) -  C# part of the page where I have used this `CustomMediaTransportControls`

Comment: In the XAML you are using `'` somewhere and somewhere else you are using `"`. Why? Try to make it `"` everywhere.

Comment: @MarianDolinský  The default style and template for MediaPlayerElement 
 control is defined in the generic.xaml was using `'` So I followed that.  I tried using `"` but it makes no difference.

Comment: That's weird, never seen `'` in XAML.. BTW, what version of W10 is your app targeting? And the code behind wouldn't work because you use name starting with `c` however the button's name starts with `C` in XAML.

Comment: @MarianDolinský Min version 14393 - Target version 15063. I used `var compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button;` to create Button. I will attach the enire code in the post.

Comment: Why such a hard way? When you define `x:Name="MyElementName"` in XAML you may use it directly in code like `MyElementName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`. No need for `GetTemplateChild` in most cases.

Comment: @MarianDolinský `MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml` is a `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: It appears that all the AppBarButtons are set to visible after the initialization. I suggest that you either add the AppBarButton and remove it completely rather than just change it visibility or that you use RegisterPropertyChangedCallback to catch the changes from the codbehind in MediaPlayer in order to change the visibility back to your value.

Comment: @Hannes Can you please provide the code? Also, AppBarButtons(CompactOverlayButton) is working properly when I first use `IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible` to change the Visibility.

Comment: @Hannes I have updated the question. Please see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if removing this one line resolved the issue since i had the same issue without this line of code. However i found a workaround for this problem:

Add a Property for the visibility as well as the according listener:

```
public Visibility CompactOverlayButtonVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(CompactOverlayButtonVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CompactOverlayButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CompactOverlayButtonVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CompactOverlayButtonVisibility) , typeof(Visibility), typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, OnVisibisityChanged));


internal static void OnVisibisityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
    if (((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).compactOverlayButton != null)
    {
        if ((Visibility)e.NewValue != Visibility.Visible)
            ((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove(((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).compactOverlayButton);
        else if (!((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Contains(((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).compactOverlayButton))
            ((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Insert(4, ((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).compactOverlayButton);
        ((CustomMediaTransportControls)d).compactOverlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

And add the following to your OnApplyTemplateMethod:

```
commandBar = GetTemplateChild("MediaControlsCommandBar") as CommandBar;
        compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as AppBarButton;
if (CompactOverlayButtonVisibility != Visibility.Visible)
    commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove(compactOverlayButton);
else if(!commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Contains(compactOverlayButton))
    commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Insert(4, compactOverlayButton);
compactOverlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

However you might want to investigate why the Visibility is changed from code despite being set in the xaml code. Maybe this is true for all AppBarButtons maybe not. You could try that out and then look into the relevant sourcecode [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com). If you found the reason you might figure out a better solution.